# How to use sed-awk-gawk to display a matched string

Tags: sed

I've got a file called 'res' that's 29374 characters of http data in a one-line string. Inside it, there are several http links, but I only want to be display those that end in '/idNNNNNNNNN' where N is a digit. In fact I'm only interested in the string 'idNNNNNNNNN'.
I've tried with:

```
cat res | sed -n '0,/.*\(id[0-9]*\).*/s//\1/p'
```

but I get the whole file.
Do you know a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -n -E 'say $1 while m!/id(\d{9})!g' input-file
```

should work. That assumes exactly 9 digits; that's the `{9}` in the above. You can match 8 or 9 (`{8,9}`), 8 or more (`{8,}`), up to 9 (`{0,9}`), etc.

Example of this working:

```
$ echo -n 'junk jumk http://foo/id231313 junk lalala http://bar/id23123 asda' | perl -n -E 'say $1 while m!id(\d{0,9})!g'
231313
23123
```

That's with the 0 to 9 variant, of course.

If you're stuck with a pre-5.10 perl, use `-e` instead of `-E` and `print "$1\n"` instead of `say $1`.

## How it works

First is the two command-line arguments to Perl. `-n` tells Perl to read input from standard input or files given on the command line, line by line, setting `$_` to each line. `$_` is perl's default target for a lot of things, including regular expression matches. `-E` merely tells Perl that the next argument is a Perl one-liner, using the new language features (vs. `-e` which does not use the 5.10 extensions).

So, looking at the one liner: `say` means to print out some value, followed by a newline. `$1` is the first regular expression capture (captures are made by parentheses in regular expressions). `while` is a looping construct, which you're probably familiar with. `m` is the match operator, the `!` after it is the regular expression delimiter (normally, you see `/` here, but since the pattern contains `/` it's easier to use something else, so you don't have to escape the `/` as `\/`). `/id(\d{9})` is the regular expression to match. Keep in mind that the delimiter is `!`, so the `/` is not special, it just matches a literal `/`. The parentheses form a capture group, so `$1` will be the number. The `!` is the delimiter, followed by `g` which means to match as many times as possible (as opposed to once). This is what makes it pick up all the URLs in the line, not just the first. As long as there is a match, the `m` operator will return a true value, so the loop will continue (and run that `say $1`, printing out the match).

## Two-sed solution

I *think* this is one way to do this with only sed. Much more complicated!

```
echo 'junk jumk http://foo/id231313 junk lalala http://bar/id23123 asda' | \
    sed 's!http://!\nhttp://!g' | \
    sed 's!^.*/id\([0-9]*\).*$!\1!'
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! Two things: 1) I'm not very used to perl syntax, so could you please explain it? 2) Is it possible to do with awk-gawk-sed?

Comment: @Morphy: If you routinely do text processing like this, perl is *the* tool for the job. I'll add in an explanation as to how that works. Sed can definitely do it, but I'm not sure how (worst case, you could probably split the lines with one sed, then match with a second).

Comment: @Morphy: I found you a sed-only solution, too. Much more complicated, but it appears to work.

Comment: @Morphy: Then you'd have to change the regexp to match whatever you want. e.g., you could have (untested) `(http://blah\.com/kdivw/id\d+)` (`+` is a shortcut for `{1,}`: one or more)

Comment: Thanks again, but I only know the domain `blah.com`, how can I match anything from `.com` to `id12345678`?

Comment: Anything from `blah.com` through the ID would be `(http://blah\.com/.+?/id\d+)` The `.` means anything except newline, the `+` one or more, and the `?` means but as few as possible (by default, its as many as possible, which you definitely don't want here, it'd match across multiple links).

Comment: Pretty nice, thanks and definitely solved. Thanks also to you all guys, good joob :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat res | perl -ne 'chomp; print "$1\n" if m/\/(id\d*)/'
```

Comment: That will display the entire line ("29374 chars http data one line string" from the question)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get anything

Comment: do you actually mean each of these lines have a html text with several links ??

Comment: There is only one line in the file!

Comment: Thanks Zimbabao it works but it displays only one occurence, where there're 6

Comment: I thought you have several lines with links. My understanding was bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that sed and grep and awk work on lines, and you've only got one line.  So, you probably need to split things up so you have more than one line -- then you can make the normal tools work.

```
tr ':' '\012' < res |
sed -n 's%.*/\(id[0-9][0-9]*\).*%\1%p'
```

This takes advantage of URLs containing colons and maps colons to newlines with `tr`, then uses `sed` to pick up anything up to a slash, followed by `id` and one or more digits, followed by anything, and prints out the id and digit string (only).  Since these only occur in URLs, they will only appear one per line and relatively near the start of the line too.

Comment: Almost! That, returns: id257593647
id257593647
id257593647�</a></div></li><li><div class="res indent"><div><h3><a class="yschttl spt" href="http
id257593647
id257593647
id257593647�</a></div></li><li><div class="res"><div><h3><a class="yschttl spt" href="http
Anyway, thanks again and if you please, add a short explanation to this newbie ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using only one invocation of `sed`:

```
sed -n 's| |\n|g;/^http/{s|http://[^/]*/id\([0-9]*\)|\1|;P};D' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `s| |\n|g;` - Divide and conquer
- `/^http/{` - If pattern space begins with "http"

  - `s|http://[^/]*/id\([0-9]*\)|\1|;` - capture the id
  - `P` - Print the string preceding the first newline
- `};` - end if
- `D` - Delete the string preceding the first newline regardless of whether it contains "http"

**Edit:**

This version uses the same technique but is more selective.

```
sed -n 's|http://|\n&|g;/^\n*http/{s|\n*http://[^/]*/id\([0-9]*\)|\1\n|;P};D' inputfile
```

Comment: Sorry Dennis, but that returns `http-equiv="content-type"`